# MySql 8.0 Foreign Keys Missing in InnoDB

Tags: innodb, foreign-key, mysql-8.0

I have created 10 tables in MySql 8.0 using the InnoDB engine. I defined relationships using the `references` statement.

When I view the tables using `show create table`, the foreign keys are missing. I have also done a mysqldump, where the keys are also missing.

Where have my foreign keys gone?

Here is a sample of one of the tables.

```
create table test (
testNumber bigint not null primary key auto_increment,
productNumber bigint not null references product (productNumber) on delete cascade on update cascade 

);
```

Comment: show us an example of the create table you used.

Comment: I updated the main question with a create table sample.

Comment: See my answer. I suspected as much ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please show us an example of `CREATE TABLE` you used.

My suspicion is that you used inline references (which are **ignored**). See MySQL documentation if that's the case, [`CREATE TABLE` Statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table.html), where it states:

> MySQL parses but ignores “inline `REFERENCES` specifications” (as defined in the SQL standard) where the references are defined as part of the column specification. MySQL accepts `REFERENCES` clauses **only when specified as part of a separate `FOREIGN KEY` specification**. For more information, see [Section 1.7.2.3, “`FOREIGN KEY` Constraint Differences”](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/ansi-diff-foreign-keys.html).

(even more details in the above second documentation page).

> - MySQL parses but ignores “inline `REFERENCES` specifications” (as defined in the SQL standard) where the references are defined as part of the column specification. MySQL accepts `REFERENCES` clauses only when specified as part of a separate `FOREIGN KEY` specification.
> - Defining a column to use a `REFERENCES tbl_name(col_name)` clause has no actual effect and serves only as a memo or comment to you that the column which you are currently defining is intended to refer to a column in another table. It is important to realize when using this syntax that:
>
>   - MySQL does not perform any sort of check to make sure that col_name actually exists in tbl_name (or even that tbl_name itself exists).
>   - MySQL does not perform any sort of action on tbl_name such as deleting rows in response to actions taken on rows in the table which you are defining; in other words, this syntax induces no `ON DELETE` or `ON UPDATE` behavior whatsoever. (Although you can write an `ON DELETE` or `ON UPDATE` clause as part of the `REFERENCES` clause, **it is also ignored**.)
>   - This syntax creates a column; it does not create any sort of index or key.

As an example, the following definition creates the column but **does not create a foreign key**, the **`REFERENCES person(id)`** (is parsed for correctness but) **has no effect at all**, no foreign key is created and no index:

```
CREATE TABLE shirt (
    id SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    style ENUM('t-shirt', 'polo', 'dress') NOT NULL,
    color ENUM('red', 'blue', 'orange', 'white', 'black') NOT NULL,
    owner SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL REFERENCES person(id),
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

---

If you want to create a foreign key in MySQL, you'll have to use the following syntax instead - which does create a foreign key (and an index as well):

```
CREATE TABLE shirt (
    id SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    style ENUM('t-shirt', 'polo', 'dress') NOT NULL,
    color ENUM('red', 'blue', 'orange', 'white', 'black') NOT NULL,
    owner SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    FOREIGN KEY (owner) REFERENCES person(id),   -- creates an FK
);
```